# How to check for a ForeignKey that no longer exists?

Tags: python, django

```
class PersonSite(models.Model):
    vps_id             = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    person             = models.ForeignKey(CanonPerson, db_column='p_id',null=True)
    site               = models.ForeignKey(CanonSite, db_column='s_id',null=True)

person_sites = PersonSite.objects.filter(person=cp)
for person_site in person_sites:
    if person_site and person_site.site_id and person_site.site.s_id:
       # crashes for some records
```

We have a problem with the data, where `PersonSite` may point to a `site` that no longer exists.
In the debugger I can see that `person_site.site_id` has a value of 5579, however that id doesn't exist in the database:

```
select * from tbl_vpd_sites where s_id = 5579
```

Hence `person_site.site_id` is not null, yet just accessing `person_site.site` within the conditional crashes the app with the message:

```
DoesNotExist: CanonSite matching query does not exist.
```

This is a very difficult situation, I can't even check for this case to bypass it.

Comment: What about replacing `person_site.site.s_id` with `CanonSite.objects.filter(pk=s_id).count()`?

Comment: That would mean I make a call to database for each iteration in the loop. Maybe there is a better way to catch the exception. This is something I am trying now.

Comment: Yes. And `.count()` is the old, you should use `.exists()`.

Comment: PersonSite.site has null=True, so it makes sense that you have to check if a object is there before accessing it.

Comment: Try this from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist.

Comment: You can also filter `person_sites = PersonSite.objects.filter(person=cp).filter(site __isnull=False)` this will give you the SQL query `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PersonSite.site has `null=True`, so it makes sense that you have to check if a object exists before accessing it.

In stead of doing all those checks `if person_site and person_site.site_id and person_site.site.s_id:` you can just query the db and filter the empty sites out.

```
person_sites = PersonSite.objects.filter(person=cp).filter(site__isnull=False)
```

This will return only the PersonSite objects where site `IS NOT NULL` and therefore have a pk.